# What needs to be explicity bundled

Tags: android, bundle

When bundling an object for later retrieval do I have to bundle objects within those objects?

For example, if I have an object that represents a player in a card game and within that I instantiate an object that represents the player's hand, do I have save the inner object to the bundle or is that automatically included with the outer one?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bundle any old `Object`, it has to be a `String` or a primitive such as `boolean`, `integer`, 'byte' or an array of these simple things. In this case yes, the contents of a `String[]` array are saved with the Bundle.

For more complex structures you can use implement the `Parcelable` in your object class, but it will be up to you to make sure the object saves all necessary information to it's Parcel and restores it.

Answer (score 0):

java.ui.Serializable is something worth checking. It pretty much automates bundling class and its member variables as long as your class and all required members implement Serializable interface too.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: That what I am using. The question is whether it automatically bundles all the objects that the thing I am bundling includes within it. The other classes are also defined as Serializable.